# error:The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

i have a listbox and when i select an item from this listbox called as ListofKBrands1, i take this error message:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

In code-behind,place of this error:

```
if (co.Company != null)
```

my code:

```
private void ListofKBrands1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RSPDbContext c = new RSPDbContext();

        if (ListofKBrands1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            ListBoxItem item = ListofKBrands1.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
            KBrand co = item.Tag as KBrand;

            if (ListofKBrands1.SelectedItem != null)
                txtNewKBrand.Text = co.Name;
            else
                txtNewKBrand.Text = "";

            int count = 0;
            if (co.Company != null)
            {
                foreach (string a in cbCompany.Items)
                {
                    if (a == co.Company.Name)
                        cbCompany.SelectedIndex = count;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else
                cbCompany.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

before error:

[image]

my KBrand.cs:

```
public class KBrand {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

company.cs:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

if company of selected KBrand is null, this error does not appear. but if company of selected KBrand is not null, i take this error.how can i fix this error ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Company` should be lazy-loaded in your case. But your entity now in detached state (context which loaded `KBrand` entity now disposed. So, when you are trying to access `Company` property, Entity Framework tries to use disposed context to make query to server. That gives you exception.

You need to attach your `KBrand` entity to current context in order to enable [lazy-loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx)

```
RSPDbContext c = new RSPDbContext();
KBrand co = item.Tag as KBrand;
c.KBrands.Attach(co);
// use co.Company
```

OR you need to use [eager loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx), to have `Company` already loaded. Something like this when you getting items:

```
RSPDbContext db = new RSPDbContext();
var brands = db.KBrands.Include(b => b.Company).ToList();
// assign brands to listbox
```

Comment: thank you very much.. i have tried the first suggestion and it Works.i have tried second one about eager loading but it did not recognized b.

Comment: @rockenpeace generic method defined in namespace `System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions`. Also you can use `Include("Company")` instead

Comment: @rockenpeace see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26177658/426315). in EF6 you need to use namespace `System.Data.Entity`, since  `System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions` does *not* exists.

Answer (score 1):

To just add to Sergey's point,

Instead of this,

```
RSPDbContext db = new RSPDbContext();
var brands = db.KBrands.Include(b => b.Company).ToList();
// assign brands to listbox
```

This worked for me..

```
RSPDbContext db = new RSPDbContext();
var brands = db.KBrands.Include("Company").ToList();
// assign brands to listbox
```

Comment: typed lambda much more better then hardcoded constant

Comment: add using System.Data.Entity; for the lambda expression to work

Comment: What should I do if `Include` doesn't help at all? I'm struggling with this problem with no success...