# Where is .Include DbExtension for EF 6.0?

Tags: entity-framework

Was DbExtensions lib not included for EF 6.0? I have a generic repo that returns and IQueryable and I'd like to be able to call .Include(i => i.SomeEntity) on demaind when needed.

Comment: Yeah, we are having the same issue with a 3rd party software that uses DBExtension.  After we upgraded to Entity Framework 6, some of our pages broke.  Just seems like a weird move on Microsoft's part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question. You don't make a reference to System.Data.Entity for version 6 to get the DbExtensions. You need to reference the EntityFramework itself and add using System.Data.Entity at the top of your cs file and the .Include() will be there.

Answer (score 3):

For EF 6.0 these functions are now available in `System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions` within `EntityFramework.dll`:

```
public static IQueryable Include(this IQueryable source, string path);

public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string path);

public static IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `using System.Data.Entity;`.

Comment: Yes you need to still add that using statement, but the dll of the same name doesn't do it for EF 6